# Webpack throws error when trying to build JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

There are so many answers to this question on SO, I swear i've tried them all. I am not sure what is wrong with config setup

The Error I get when running webpack in the terminal:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     // const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
|     return (
>         <HomeShell/>
|     );
| };
```

my index.js

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HomeShell from "./HomeShell";

const Root  = () => {

    return (
        <HomeShell/>
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('#main'));
```

^^ HomeShell is js file with React Components that are all js files.

My webpack.config.cjs

```
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'

    },
    target: "web",
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                include: /src/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "site name here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "site desc",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git url"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "issues url"
  },
  "homepage": "readme url",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && webpack && babel server -s -d dist",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "production": "npm run build && node bin/production",
    "start": "npm run production"
  }
}
```

I am far from an expert on react/webpack/babel but this exact setup seems to work fine on another basic app I have running. Not sure what I am doing different between the two apps.

Comment: Are you sure your `webpack.config.cjs` is being loaded? If you put a `console.log` in it, does it print out?

Comment: @loganfsmyth you were right. it wasnt being loaded. I didnt realize with the new .cjs ending that you needed to pass it in the --config  option in the terminal/build script. Everything works great. If you post as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using a `webpack.config.cjs` file, which at the moment anyway, Webpack does not support by default: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1165

You'd need to explicitly pass `--config webpack.config.cjs` option to load this file.

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

in your `.babelrc` file and also in the loader options. Maybe there is a conflict.

Comment: Just removed the the preset options in the loader options of my webpack.config.cjs and still got the same error.

Comment: Comparing to others configs I have, the only thing I see that could help is using this in your `.babelrc` file 
`{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}`
instead of `{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}`